# tinymce tries to save after remove()

Tags: javascript, tinymce

When I remove tinymce from a textarea (using `tinymce.editors[0].remove()` or `tinymce.get('mytextareasid').remove()`) it then tries to save, so I get the following exceptions:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'designMode' of null
```

(the second one is caused by my save handler).  What should I change so tinyMCE doesn't try to save after it's been removed?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the editor instance by using

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, textarea_id);
```

In this case `save()` should not be called.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's calling `save()`... but my save handler gets called after doing that

Answer (score 0):

the `get` function tries to save the instance when it finds it (after it finishes with the added functions you were trying to make on the instance. In this case the `remove` function). What is happening is that you are removing the instance (that's why it's `null`) and then trying to save it with the `get` function. I would suggest the following code:

```
tiny_ed = tinymce.get('mytextareasid')
tinyMCE.remove(tiny_ed);
```